# Confused about the definition of 'abstraction' in OOP

Tags: oop, abstraction

I am trying to understand the definition of 'abstraction' in OOP.

I have come across two main definitions. Are they both valid? Is one of them wrong? I'm confused. (I re-wrote the definition with my own words).

**Definition 1:**

Abstraction is the concept of taking some object from the real world, and converting it to programming terms. Such as creating a `Human` class and giving it `int health`, `int age`, `String name`, etc. properties, and `eat()` etc. methods.

**Definition 2:**

A more general definition. Abstraction is a concept that takes place **anywhere** in a software system where ***'making things more general/simpler/abstract'*** is involved. A few examples:

- An inheritance hierarchy, where the higher classes are simpler or more general,
  and define more general and abstract implementation.
  While the lower classes in the hierarchy are more concrete and define
  more detailed implementations.
- Using encapsulation to hide the details of implementation of a class from other classes, thus making the class more 'abstract' (simpler) to the outside software world.

Is any of these definitions correct?

(I am referring to the most conventional and accepted definition).

Comment: I think both are reasonable, they're used in different contexts. This discussion would probably be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Timothy Budd defined it in his 1991 text, "An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming", as "the ability to encapsulate and isolate design and execution information.  In one sense, Object-Oriented techniques can be seen to be a natural outcome of a long historical progression from procedures, to modules, to abstract data types and objects." Injecting my own opinion, when you migrate the focus from **how** to do stuff to **which operations** are available for **which types of things**, you're abstracting.

Comment: @pjs So basically, abstraction is the concept of moving the focus from the details and concrete implementation of things, to the types of things (i.e. classes), the operations available (i.e. methods), etc, thus making the programming simpler, more general, and more *abstract*. This takes place for example when encapsulating, because encapsulation means to hide the details of implementation and only show the types of things and their more general and *abstract* definitions. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Prog Sounds like a pretty good summary to me! With abstraction, you don't worry about the implementation.  In fact, with a good abstract interface the backing implementation could be completely revised without altering how the users of that abstraction utilize it. I like the example of the controls for audio tapes, cd players, vcr's, and dvd's - everybody throughout the world knows what the play, reverse, stop, and pause buttons do even though the underlying technologies are radically different.

Comment: @pjs Would you say this definition is conventional and widely accepted?

Comment: @Prog I believe so, but others should certainly weigh in here. Have you encountered abstract data types (ADTs)? As an example, a stack is an abstraction which allows you to push and pop data on a LIFO basis, and to peek at the top element. The implementer needs to make implementation choices, but the users of it don't need to know about how it's implemented. They use it through its interface (push, pop, peek) and for its LIFO functionality. Ditto for most well-constructed data structures and libraries.